# Division without using division, multiplication, or modulus operators

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6, bitwise

**The task**

> Implement division of two positive integers without using the
>   division, multiplication, or modulus operators. Return the quotient as
>   an integer, ignoring the remainder.

**My solution**

```
const division = (dividend, divisor) => {
    let remainder = null;
    let quotient = 1;
    const sign = ((dividend > 0 && divisor < 0) || 
                 (dividend < 0 && divisor > 0)) ? 
                 ~1 : 1;

    let tempdividend = Math.abs(dividend);
    let tempdivisor = Math.abs(divisor);

    if (tempdivisor === tempdividend) {
        remainder = 0;
        return sign;
    } else if (tempdividend < tempdivisor) {
        remainder = dividend < 0 ? 
            sign < 0 ? ~tempdividend : tempdividend : 
            tempdividend;
        return 0;
    }
    while (tempdivisor << 1 <= tempdividend) {
        tempdivisor = tempdivisor << 1;
        quotient = quotient << 1;
    }

    quotient = dividend < 0 ? 
        (sign < 0 ? ~quotient : quotient) + division(~(tempdividend-tempdivisor), divisor) :
        (sign < 0 ? ~quotient : quotient) + division(tempdividend-tempdivisor, divisor);
    return quotient;
 }
```

Comment: Your function does not work, very sloppy. I am amazed you found two arguments that would return the correct result. `division(-1,1)` returns `-2,  `-2 / -1` returns `3` and worst any value divide 0 does not return at all.

Comment: It works for positive integers (as the task ask for). But you are right about the other stuff. Will fix it. @Blindman67

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is bitwise operation mandatory? There's a much simpler way

```
const divide = (dividend, divisor) => {
     let quotient = 0, neg = false;

     if( (dividend < 0 && divisor > 0) || (dividend > 0 && divisor < 0) ){ neg = true; }

     dividend = Math.abs(dividend);
     divisor = Math.abs(divisor);

     if(dividend < divisor) {return 0;}
     else if(dividend > 0 && divisor != 0){
          while(dividend >= divisor){
               dividend -= divisor;
               ++quotient;
          }
     } else { // handle what you want to do for those cases..}

     return neg ? -quotient : quotient;
}
```

You get your quotient and remainder is ignored. Just do a check if dividend is negative or divisor is 0.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Better check dividend sign *before* comparing to divisor.

Comment: Also first if statement should be `<` not `>` and ... It may be the simple way, but divide(2**32-1, 1) may take some time to complete (On average device 11 seconds), even longer if its `divide(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, -1)`  (about 22 years on average device) There is a point where  complexity provides practical solutions.

Comment: @greybeard I have fixed my answer to accommodate the negative cases. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Blindman67 I have fixed the comparison. As for the division case, your case is a valid example that I have taken into account before posting the answer. However, there is no one solution to solve them all, and I thought if the OP was handling smaller cases (possible range was not mentioned), and has already a solution to handle complex cases, why not a simpler one then.

Comment: @Dblaze47 Oh my bad, my numbers were way wrong  32Bit int is ~7 seconds, and MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is about ~5 months. Anyways besides the point, "Why not a simpler one then."  Why? This is code review, the focus is the review of OP's code, its style, its logic, and with that you can add example alternative/s demonstrating the points reviewed. The OP is after all looking for feedback on their code. If alternatives were the quest then google would be the better path, don't you think.

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks for your feedback. Actually the OP didn't ask for any alternatives, but just stated the task and what was his solution. So I just assumed the task required help and suggested an alternate. You are right, this is not Stackoverflow. I will keep this in mind for all future references.